# Função DELETE com php e mysql

Tags: php

**deleta.php:**

```
<?php
// quero transformar esse script em função e chama-lo no link
// deleta um unico post
        include("config.php");
        $id = $_GET['id'];  
        $sqlInsert = "DELETE FROM conteudo WHERE id = '$id'";   
        $deletaPost = mysqli_query($conecta,$sqlInsert);

    if($deletaPost) {
            header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
            exit;
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($conecta);
    }

 // o script abaixo deleta através de um checkbox, e elimina varios de uma vez.
// quero que esse seja o padrão, e o script acima seja uma função que só funcione quando chamada.
    if( !empty( $_POST['deletar'] ) ) {
       $groups = array_chunk( $_POST['deletar'], 50 );
       foreach ( $groups AS $group ) {
    $group = implode('\',\'', $_POST['deletar']);
            $query = 'DELETE FROM conteudo WHERE id IN (\''. $group .'\')';
           $deleta = mysqli_query($conecta, $query);
          // executa a query
       }

        if($deleta) {
           header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
           exit;
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($conecta);
    }

    } else {
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
           exit;
    }

    ?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="deleta.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Excluir</a>
```

Como devo fazer para transformar o script de deletar em uma função, e em seguida chama no link?
 Quero fazer isso porque na pagina deleta.php eu já tenho outro script, e os dois estão dando conflitos. Com isso, decidi transformar o script em função e chama-la no link. Como agir

Comment: você pode deletar mais de um registro por link?

Comment: Não, com um checkbox em uma outra parte do código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma função ela pode receber dois argumentos, o primero é a conexão e o segundo o `id` a ser excluído, faça a validação se entra enviada pelo usuário é número, caso positivo efetue o delete e retorne `true`, pega o retorna da função e redirecione o usuario em caso de sucesso.

No link, você deve continuar a chamar o arquivo delete.php e nele fazer a chamada da função.

delete.php

```
include 'conexao.php';
function delete($conexao, $id){
   //código a ser desenvolvido
}

$id = isset($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
if(delete($conexao, $id)){
   header('delteSucesso.php');
}else{
   echo 'erro ao excluír o registro';
}
```

Comment: E como ficaria meu link chamando a função? A estrutura da função ficaria assim?: function deleta($conecta, $row['id']) {...} e o link: href="deleta.php?id=<?php include('config.php'); function deleta($conecta, $row['id']); ?>

Comment: @ThiagoBarros fica a mesma coisa

Comment: Como eu transformo em função então? É que na pagina deleta.php tem o script de deletar por id, e logo abaixo tem um script que funciona com um checkbox, que eu uso para deletar varios registros de uma vez..

Comment: Eu deixei sem transformar em função e tentei deletar, mesmo existindo os dois scripts. Quando tentei deletar, funcionou, mas ao invez de redirecionar, eu recebi a mensagem: Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de '' � la ligne 1. Ao tentar utilizar o script abaixo, não funcionou. Será que é melhor criar uma pagina pra cada script?

Comment: Parece ser erro do banco, o ideal que delete.php só tenho código php e nenhum html.

Comment: Não tem nenhum HTML. Eu irei atualizar o post com o meu deleta.php completo. O que eu quero é transformar o primeiro script que deleta por ID em uma função e chama-la no link.